# Python function inside with open file: only the first list comprehention 'called' working properly?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a csv file with multiple and repeated values. Mounted a giant list with lots of dictionaries with each value of list with csv.DictReader, separated the fields like this: (fieldnames=['person', 'food', 'weekday']).

I don't think the csv file content matters for the problem, so I'm not copying it.

Mostly of problems, I just needed to find a filtered value, so I used a Counter and/or list with comprehension.

Right now I need to find the difference between all possible 'food' and the 'food' consumed by one specific 'person'.

So I need to compare two list with list comprehension.

My code:

```
import csv
from typing import Counter

def analyze_log(path_to_file):
    with open(path_to_file) as f:
        csv_opened_file = csv.DictReader(
            f, fieldnames=['name', 'food', 'weekday'])


        def person_favorite_meal(opened_file, person):
            person_orders = Counter(
                order['food'] for order in opened_file if order['name'] == person
            )  # this works
            return max(person_orders, key=person_orders.get)


        def person_how_many_ordered(opened_file, person, meal):
            person_orders = Counter(
                order['food'] for order in opened_file if order['name'] == person and order['food'] == meal
            )  # this works
            return person_orders[meal]


        def person_never_ordered(opened_file, person):
            every_ordered_meal = Counter([order['food'] for order in opened_file])  # this works
            person_ordered_meals = Counter([
                order['food'] for order in opened_file if order['name'] == person
            ])  # this DOESN'T work
            
            list_difference = [
                meal for meal in every_ordered_meal if meal not in person_ordered_meals]

            return f"1- {person_ordered_meals} 2- {every_ordered_meal}"


print(person_never_ordered(csv_opened_file, 'maria'))
analyze_log('../data/orders_1.csv') # the file is read
```

**The problem: only the first list in the function 'person_never_ordered' works properly.**

Like if I have the code like this:

```
 def person_never_ordered(opened_file, person):
            every_ordered_meal = Counter([order['food'] for order in opened_file])  # this comes first, it works
            person_ordered_meals = Counter([
                order['food'] for order in opened_file if order['name'] == person
            ])  # this DOESN'T work
            
            list_difference = [
                meal for meal in every_ordered_meal if meal not in person_ordered_meals]

            return f"1- {person_ordered_meals} 2- {every_ordered_meal}"


print(person_never_ordered(csv_opened_file, 'maria'))
analyze_log('../data/orders_1.csv') # the file is read
```

I get the console like this:

> 1- Counter() 2- Counter({'hamburguer': 33, 'pizza': 8, 'coxinha': 8,
> 'misto-quente': 7})

But if I just switch the lists order, with code like this:

```
def person_never_ordered(opened_file, person):
                person_ordered_meals = Counter([
                    order['food'] for order in opened_file if order['name'] == person
                ])  # now this comes first, and it works
    
                every_ordered_meal = Counter([order['food'] for order in opened_file])  # now this comes second first, and it doesn't work!

                
                list_difference = [
                    meal for meal in every_ordered_meal if meal not in person_ordered_meals]
    
                return f"1- {person_ordered_meals} 2- {every_ordered_meal}"
    
    
    print(person_never_ordered(csv_opened_file, 'maria'))
    analyze_log('../data/orders_1.csv') # the file is read
```

I get the console with this:

> 1- Counter({'hamburguer': 16, 'pizza': 8, 'coxinha': 8}) 2- Counter()

Why is this happening?

Comment: In the given code, the `person_never_ordered()` function is defined _inside_ of the `analyze_log()` function, so it would not be callable at the outermost level.  Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: @JohnGordon that's totally unrelated with the question, and it ignores the 'console' result. I call the function and I get the return f"1- {person_ordered_meals} 2- {every_ordered_meal}" to demonstrate that.

The problem is It just returns which one I put first. Observe those last two pieces of code, I switched the lines of the 'person_ordered_meals' with 'every_ordered_meal'.

Comment: @CrazyChucky kinda does! It's strange. If I print the 'opened_file' before and after, the first printed is alright, the second one is empty.

Thank you.

Comment: It is _absolutely_ related to the question.  As shown, `person_never_ordered()` is not callable at the outermost level.  And yet you are calling it successfully, therefore your real code must not be as shown.  It's very hard to help when you don't show us the real code.

Answer (score -1):

you cant call a function that is defined inside another function like that make it you have to define your functions globally in order to be able to use them in the rest of your code

fix:

- move the definition outside the analyze function
- or try adding global before each definition

Comment: That is a problem with the code as presented, but based on the question, it is not the problem the asker is experiencing. It would appear that the code they actually ran is properly indented. This would be better as  a comment than an answer; and, in fact, it already is (by John Gordon).